# How to assign innertext with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

The following jsfiddle uses this example:

```
<span id="test1">some text</span>
<span id="test2">some text</span>
```

onLoad

```
alert($('test1').text();
$('test2').text('different text');
```

However, when the alert appears, it says:

```
"http://fiddle.jshell.net"
```

and text2 isn't assigned.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/EuwMQ/1/

Comment: Just for reference, you're missing a closing bracket on your alert.

Comment: Oh, and you need to use '#test1' etc in your jQuery selectors if you're using id's

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 problems :

- a missing parenthesis
- a missing # to look for element by id

Try this :

```
alert($('#test1').text());
$('#test2').text('different text');
```

When debugging JavaScript, you'd better use `console.log` instead of `alert` : it's much more convenient. [Opening the console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) would also have shown you the first syntax error.

Comment: The jsfiddle example has the parentheses but I don't have it in the above example.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a hash tag.

Should be:

```
$('#test2').text('different text');
```